# How do I fix this python hand tracking with mediapipe and open-cv error?

Tags: python, opencv, typeerror, mediapipe

So I am following this tutorial:[Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZde8Xt78Iw&t=0s) I cannot seem to get the HandTrackingModule working. The HandTrackingMin works fine. The difference is that I put all the code in a function and run it in the Module but in the min i just run it. The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\danes\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm2023.1\scratches\scratch_2.py", line 122, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\danes\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm2023.1\scratches\scratch_2.py", line 102, in main
    detector = handDetector()
  File "C:\Users\danes\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm2023.1\scratches\scratch_2.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands,
  File "C:\Users\danes\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solutions\hands.py", line 114, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\danes\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 289, in __init__
    self._input_side_packets = {
  File "C:\Users\danes\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 290, in <dictcomp>
    name: self._make_packet(self._side_input_type_info[name], data)
  File "C:\Users\danes\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 592, in _make_packet
    return getattr(packet_creator, 'create_' + packet_data_type.value)(data)
TypeError: create_int(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (arg0: int) -> mediapipe.python._framework_bindings.packet.Packet

Invoked with: 0.5

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Does anyone recognize this error?

I tried many different things. I even ended up copying and pasting tutorial code to see if it would work and I still get the same error.

Edit: here is the code

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time


class handDetector():
    def __init__(self, mode=False, hand_complexity=1, maxHands=2, detectionCon=0.5, trackCon=0.5):
        self.handcom = hand_complexity
        self.mode = mode
        self.maxHands = maxHands
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon
        self.trackCon = trackCon

        self.mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
        self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands,
                                        self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)
        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

    def findHands(self, img, draw=True):
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.results = self.hands.process(imgRGB)
        # print(results.multi_hand_landmarks)

        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for handLms in self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                if draw:
                    self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, handLms,
                                               self.mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
        return img

    def findPosition(self, img, handNo=0, draw=True):

        lmList = []
        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            myHand = self.results.multi_hand_landmarks[handNo]
            for id, lm in enumerate(myHand.landmark):
                # print(id, lm)
                h, w, c = img.shape
                cx, cy = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)
                # print(id, cx, cy)
                lmList.append([id, cx, cy])
                if draw:
                    cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 15, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)

        return lmList


def main():
    pTime = 0
    cTime = 0
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    detector = handDetector()
    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        img = detector.findHands(img)
        lmList = detector.findPosition(img)
        if len(lmList) != 0:
            print(lmList[4])

        cTime = time.time()
        fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime)
        pTime = cTime

        cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (10, 70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,
                    (255, 0, 255), 3)

        cv2.imshow("Image", img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exactly have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .. that said, it looks like that class expects an int, but is getting a float

Comment: Hello there, you need to provide minimally reproducible code snippet so we can reproduce your error and give you a solution!

Comment: I put the code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a duplicate of [[SO]: Type error: create_bool(): incompatible function arguments. Need some advice on this one (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74304767/4788546), but I'm going to elaborate.

According to [[GitHub]: google/mediapipe - (v0.10.3) mediapipe/mediapipe/python/solutions/hands.py](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/v0.10.3/mediapipe/python/solutions/hands.py) (latest at answer time, same on *master* branch), *Hands* initializer (around line *#89*) is:

> ```py
>   def __init__(self,
>                static_image_mode=False,
>                max_num_hands=2,
>                model_complexity=1,
>                min_detection_confidence=0.5,
>                min_tracking_confidence=0.5):
> ```

The arguments you pass don't match expected ones (missing *model_complexity*) making it treat what you pass as *min_detection_confidence* as if it actually was *model_complexity*.

To avoid running into this kind of error, **use keyword arguments** when initializing *Hands* (and in general). In your code, instead of calling the initializer as you currently do:

```py
self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands,
                                self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)
```

call it like this:

```py
self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(
    static_image_mode=self.mode,
    max_num_hands=self.maxHands,
    model_complexity=self.handcom,  # @TODO - cfati: might also add missing argument
    min_detection_confidence=self.detectionCon,
    min_tracking_confidence=self.trackCon)
```

Comment: What do you mean by keyword arguments? Would I just replace the __init__ with that?

Comment: Edited the answer to be more clear. But since you don't know what keyword arguments are, perhaps you should first go through https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted.